# wikia.org editor highlighting for Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

Anyone know where i can get something similar to this wiki's editor (http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Radio_Stations?action=edit) for my mediawiki wiki?

[image: colored stuff]

Answer (score 3):

[CodeMirror](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CodeMirror) and [WikEd](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikEd) can both do that.

Answer (score 2):

[Remember the dot/Syntax highlighter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Remember_the_dot/Syntax_highlighter) is similar.